# R get first letters of double/tripple-barrel surnames in data.frame

Tags: regex, r, string, strsplit

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
> df1
      Surname      Name
1 The Builder       Bob
2 Zeta-Jones Catherine
```

I want to add a third column "Shortened_Surname" which contains the first letters of all the words in the surname field:

```
      Surname      Name Shortened_Surname
1 The Builder       Bob                TB
2  Zeta-Jones Catherine                ZJ
```

Note the "-" in the second name. I have barreled surnames separated by **spaces and hyphens**.

**I have tried:**

Step1:

```
> strsplit(unlist(as.character(df1$Surname))," ")
[[1]]
[1] "The"     "Builder"

[[2]]
[1] "Zeta-Jones"
```

My research suggests I could possibly use `strtrim` as a Step 2, but all I have found is a number of ways how not to do it.

Comment: Are the letters always capitalized?

Comment: @Heroka no, but I will use `casefold` to make everything lower case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the space, hyphen, and beginning of the line with lookarounds.  For instance, you any character (`.`) not preceded by the beginning of the line, a space, or a hyphen should be substituted to "":

```
with(df, gsub("(?<!^|[ -]).", "", Surname, perl=TRUE))
[1] "TB" "ZJ"
```

or

```
with(df, gsub("(?<=[^ -]).", "", Surname, perl=TRUE))
```

The second `gsub` substitutes a blank (`""`) for any character that is preceded by a character that is not a `" "` or `"-"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, if the format of the names is as show in the input data:

```
library(stringr)
df$Shortened_Surname <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$Surname, '[A-Z]{1}'), function(x) paste(x, collapse = ''))
```

Output is as follows:

```
      Surname      Name Shortened_Surname
1 The Builder       Bob                TB
2  Zeta-Jones Catherine                ZJ
```

If the format of the names is somewhat inconsistent, you will need to modify the above pattern to capture that. You can use `|, &` operators inside the pattern to combine multiple patterns.